# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘com.facebook.sdk.FBSDKCoreKit’ is correct. (Here my package is com.helo.app

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, bundle-identifier

I am getting the error as No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘com.facebook.sdk.FBSDKCoreKit’ is correct while trying to upload to testflight.

But my bundle identifier shows the correct identifier (com.helo.app) and in the build settings also shows (com.helo.app)

Xcode: 13.2.1

No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘com.facebook.sdk.FBSDKCoreKit’ is correct.

Note:

I also noticed the ipa generated shows as FBSDKCoreKit.ipa as its name. It is entirely wrong and how can I check this and how can I generate as per the target name. I have the correct target name, but the ipa name alone got changed.
[image]